# How to make a 6v6 custom match on Ecopoint: Antarctica?

Tags: overwatch

I wanted to make a custom match that was 6v6 on Ecopoint: Antarctica but I can't seem to adjust the settings right. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm having trouble with making the map be ecopoint and the number of players is 6v6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will (try) to lead you through the steps to complete this:

1. Go to **SETTINGS** and select **MODES**
2. Disable all modes except elimination, the mode you want (by default this is turned off so this might be where you are having issues.
3. Go back and select **MAPS**. Turn off every map except for ***Ecopoint: Antarctica***
4. Customize the game how you'd like it (such as health, amount of each hero, what heroes etc.)
5. Fill up your game, and hit start, this should work for you

Any issues feel free to comment and I'll try and help out :)

[image: Custom settings for 6v6 on Echopoint: Antarctica]